# React-redux reselect performance

Tags: performance, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I have a question regarding performance while using reselect in a react redux application.

The Reselect library is used as a memoization layer to cache calculations that are made for performance, but what if you do not need any calculations/logic done?

Is it more performant to use a selector for a single piece of data or should I just be using the standard connect method instead?

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem? If not, don't spend time on such things.

Comment: More so looking at it from a code simplicity and maintainability standpoint. As in does writing extra code for selectors that are just getting a single piece of state data worth it? Does the caching help in that situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As toomuchdesign has already stated. If there genuinely is no calculations/logic and the selector simply returns a reference to an object or to a value that exists somewhere in the state tree. Then there is no need for memoized selector as a shallow equality check will be done by `connect`.

Therefore, when deciding whether to use a plain selector or use `createSelector` A good question to ask is: Will the reference of this object, array or function that is returned by the selector be different each time it is executed?

Contrived example:

```
const getSelectedItems = state => state.items.filter(i => i.selected)
```

Would result in a different array each time the selector is called.

Whereas:

```
const getFullName = createSelector(
  state => state.items,
  items => items.filter(i => i.selected)
)
```

Would only return a new array if the `items` array changed.

So while it might be tempting to look at the complexity of the selectors computation as the basis of the decision, the caching of references is a key factor in enabling the performance benefits of `reselect` as it will result in less unnecessary renders. So while the memoization of a selector itself can bring performance benefits. Don't forget the performance benefits that caching the reference itself can bring.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not need any calculation/logic, write just a plain selector which accept the application state and optional further inputs as arguments. Like this:

```
const getAnItemById = (state, itemId) => state.items.find(item => item.id === itemId);
```

Then connect your selectors to your components through Redux `connect`.

Don't use `reselect` if you don't need caching/memoization superpowers!

Comment: or don't use it at all? this thing is complicated and promise little benefit on general application

Comment: This example will cause a wasted render as array.find returns a new copy of the array. Using reselect will prevent that.

Comment: @Kristfal Perhaps you are thinking about array.filter?  The array.find() doesn't return a new array, it returns the item object found with matching id, a stable reference that wouldn't lead to any more renders than a memoized version of this selector.